# \intertext messes up aligned equations

Tags: align, intertext

I wish to align several equations (and center them of course) while being able to put text between them. I have the following code :

```latex
\begin{align*}
a &= b\\
c &= d
\intertext{first text working fine}
e &= \begin{aligned}[t]{} f+g+h+j &= w \\
                                x &= y
\intertext{messes things up}
                        \Aboxed{z &= 0}
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
```

And it gives me this output :

[image]

It is the second `\intertext{}` command that does this but I didn't find a way to replace it.

How can I center my equations ?

Does someone have a clue of how I can put text in this situation ? And how can I choose if it goes all the way to the left or not all the way ?

If I remove that `\intertext{messes things up}` line, everything is nicer :

[image]

Comment: Intertext is not supported inside aligned, I think I should give you an error

Comment: The only error I get is "Overfull \hbox (18.61911pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 19--19"
Here is a link : https://www.overleaf.com/read/tcyvdtxsnddt

Comment: To me it looks fine. The second `\intertext` is part of the `aligned` environment, the reason why the text starts at the left margin of `aligned` which is vertically aligned to the `f`

Comment: Please tell us how (or in which package) `\Aboxed` is defined.

Comment: Where do you wish the argument of the second `\intertext` directive to be placed?

Comment: @daleif: There is no error.

Comment: `\Aboxed` comes from the `mathtools` package and the text placement doesn't really matter, I'd like my equations to be centered. (edited the post to precise this)

Comment: @D-Raphal: Which one centered? All or only the aligned?

Comment: the whole thing from `a=b` to `z=0`, as the align environment usually works

Answer (score 1):

Using `alignat*` solves the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
a &= b\\
c &= d
\intertext{first text working fine}
e &=  f &{}+g+h+j &= w \\
     & & x &= y \\
\intertext{doesn’t mess things any more}
      & & \Aboxed{z &= 0}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't  know enough inner details of aligned to say.  Is there any problem with `alignat*` w.r.t. your real equations?

Comment: Yes, I tried it but there is a space between the  `e=` and the `f`. I think it is because of the `d` above. In my equations, the space is much bigger, because the `d` term takes more space

Comment: Oh! I didn't notice it. I'll try to see what can be done.

Comment: I've moved  `&` just after the letter `f`, added a pair of braces right after, and it seems to be fine now.

Comment: works in this example but I've a long fraction instead of `f+g+h+j` and now the space is before the `=w`.
you can try by replacing `e &=  f &{}+g+h+j &= w \\ `  with  `e &= \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{1-\beta ^2}} &{} & =w\\ `

Comment: Could you post the fraction?

Comment: you can try with this you'll understand : 
```\begin{alignat*}{2}
a &= &=\gamma [x_2'-x_1']+v[t_2'-t_1']\\
c &= d
\intertext{first text working fine}
e &= \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{1-\beta ^2}} &{} & =w\\
     & & x &= y \\
\intertext{doesn’t mess things any more}
      & & \Aboxed{z &= 0}
\end{alignat*}```

Comment: Why do you have two consecutive `=` signs in the first row?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93514/discussion-between-d-raphal-and-bernard).